# MSSQL connection from other device in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, desktop-application, tedious

I'm new in nodejs and microsoft sql. I've created a simple project which uses mssql in my localhost.
And I connected it in my app.js with 'tedious', and everything works perfect.

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
  var Request = require('tedious').Request;
 
   var config = {
     server: 'localhost',
     authentication: {
       type: 'default',
       options: {
         userName: 'sa',
         password: '123456789',
       },
     },
     options: {
       encrypt: false,
       database: 'mydb',
     },
   };
 
   const connection = new Connection(config);
```

However, I want to make this ViualStudio project to be deployed and make desktop application and can be used by another computer, but mssql connection should not be lochost anymore right ?
What can I do, in terms of mssql connection ?
What things should I change ?

Thank you.

I haven't changed anything so far in my sql server management bcs im not sure.

Comment: And of course you will also need to adapt the config of your app to use the correct server name ... (and I'd suggest not to use `sa` but a specific user with only those privileges needed for running your app)

Comment: Thank you, I followed your link's instructions, but the only difference is I have 'Protocols for MSSQLSERVER' rather than 'SQLEXPRESS' . Does it matter ?

Comment: No, that's just the name of the database instance ...

Comment: So, in my configuration code above, do I need to change anything now?  like authentication type?

Comment: except the `server`  probably not.

Comment: After declaring a unique server name, am I ready to go to deploy the app.js, nothing is left with mssql right?